# Azure B2C: Graph API doesn't always return user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

When making a query to Azure B2C Graph API for retrieving a specific user, I noticed that sometimes  no result will be returned, but an HTTP 200 code is returned back from the Graph API server.  Our server creates a Graph API token every time we need to make a call to Graph API (will be handled in the future, but this could be why I'm getting the issue below).

The majority of these issues are occurring during our integration tests, which are written in Python.

First, we create the user in Azure B2C:

```json
Inserting test user with data:  {
   "accountEnabled":true,
   "displayName":"Patricia Robles",
   "mailNickname":"PatriciaRobles",
   "extension_<id>_organizationId":"b5468371-54e7-41d3-8dc4-904779417ce2",
   "extension_<id>_organizationName":"My Organization",
   "extension_<id>_username":"PatriciaRobles",
   "givenName":"Patricia",
   "surname":"Robles",
   "userPrincipalName":"PatriciaRobles@testb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
   "passwordProfile":{
      "password":"He#02021"
   }
}
Created in Graph API:  {
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
   "id":"5e2ae56c-4493-451f-be26-de51e05475c5",
   "businessPhones":[
      
   ],
   "displayName":"Patricia Robles",
   "givenName":"Patricia",
   "jobTitle":"None",
   "mail":"None",
   "mobilePhone":"None",
   "officeLocation":"None",
   "preferredLanguage":"None",
   "surname":"Robles",
   "userPrincipalName":"PatriciaRobles@testb2c.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

So it looks like it actually created the user in Azure B2C.  Note that I actually changed the values from the actual runtime to prevent leaking sensitive data.

Now, as a sanity check during test, I want to query all users in an organization:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=identities,givenName,id,surname&$filter=extension_<id>_organizationId eq 'b5468371-54e7-41d3-8dc4-904779417ce2'
Returned for Graph API:  {'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(identities,givenName,id,surname)', "value":[
   {
      "givenName":"Patricia",
      "id":"5e2ae56c-4493-451f-be26-de51e05475c5",
      "surname":"Robles",
      "identities":[
         {
            "signInType":"userPrincipalName",
            "issuer":"testb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId":"PatriciaRobles@testb2c.onmicrosoft.com"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "givenName":"Ruby",
      "id":"a7b2d2fe-3176-49bc-9775-691195ed9002",
      "surname":"Woodard",
      "identities":[
         {
            "signInType":"userPrincipalName",
            "issuer":"testb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId":"RubyWoodard@testb2c.onmicrosoft.com"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "givenName":"Helen",
      "id":"d97201c8-e561-4b83-aa75-441ccc069a18",
      "surname":"Charles",
      "identities":[
         {
            "signInType":"userPrincipalName",
            "issuer":"testb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId":"HelenCharles@testb2c.onmicrosoft.com"
         }
      ]
   }
]
}
```

The user definitely exists in Azure B2C.  So we definitely should be able to query for that individual user, right?

Well, not quite:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=identities,givenName,id,surname&$filter=extension_5d0e560b4ba9481d97b55226dd4c411a_organizationId eq 'b5468371-54e7-41d3-8dc4-904779417ce2' and id eq '5e2ae56c-4493-451f-be26-de51e05475c5'
Returned for Graph API:  {'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(identities,givenName,id,surname)', 'value': []}
Retrieved from Graph API:  {}
```

So now, no user is returned from Azure B2C via Graph API.

Why exactly is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a globally distributed service and you are hitting a different DC where the user has not replicated to. It can take some seconds till the user appears across all DCs in the region.

This is the expected behaviour and you must architect a solution with this in mind. You can use retry logic but ideally you do not perform a GET subsequent to a POST/PATCH operation.

Ideally you orchestrate sign up through AAD B2C policies which do not have this issue.

Comment: @jas-suri-msft, am I putting ```client-request-id``` in the header of the GET operation?  Seems that I'm still getting those random errors.  Do I need to use ```Location```?

Comment: Additionally, is there actually documentation on this stuff?

Comment: You might need to generate a client-request-id header in your POST request. Then send the same header in the GET request.

Comment: @jas-suri-msft, Hmm... It seems that I get the same issue with that approach.  I've looked through the documentation and I don't really see any references on this type of behavior.  Where is this documented?

Comment: I am going to edit this answer based on that. This approach is not documented.