# Azure B2C: Webhook Notifications of User Activity Aren't Being Picked Up

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, webhooks, azure-ad-graph-api

Due to an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930830/azure-b2c-graph-api-doesnt-always-return-user) that I've been dealing with Azure B2C, I was thinking of using [notification webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks) to receive information on when a user was created/updated.

While I'm able to create a subscription to the `users` resource, the webhook won't fire off when I actually create/update a user via the Graph API.

I created the subscription as follows:

```sh
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
{
   "changeType":"updated",
   "notificationUrl":"https://a7500b01de1c.ngrok.io/b2chook/Users",
   "resource":"users",
   "expirationDateTime":"2021-08-09T01:50:17.699528+00:00"
}
```

The webhook that's listening into the subscription is being done in Python via Flask.

Here's the current code that's written up to receive the webhook notification:

```py
class B2CUserHook(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        logger.debug(f"Microsoft Graph API notified the endpoint!")
        if "validationToken" in request.args:
            token = request.args.get('validationToken')
            #res = make_response(token, 201)
            #res.mimetype = "text/plain"
            logger.debug(f"Token to return back to Graph API: {token}")
            return Response(token, mimetype="text/plain")
        
        return Response(status=202)
```

With the url being declared as a resource:

```py
api.add_resource(user_controller.B2CUserHook, "/b2chook/Users")
```

So, how exactly can I fix this issue so that I can receive the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it in the linked document:
**Azure AD B2C tenants are not supported**

Comment: Then the question is why aren't B2C tenants supported?

Comment: Structure of B2C tenant behind the scenes prohibit  support of webhook and differential queries. There is no ETA on  support for this.

Comment: Is this also true for groups? I am trying to subscribe to group changes for my B2C users, but the notification appears to not be firing.

Comment: All “changes” are differential queries, so yes it applies to group changes too.